# Windows 7 - Deleted boot files

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, formatting

I am (was) using an install of Win7 on the C Disk Partition,

I formatted the D Disk Parition, and now Win7 fails to bootup.

I suspect the bootup config files were stored within the D Partition, despite the install residing on the C Partition.

---

> This is the error I'm getting: **Reboot and Select proper Boot device**

---

Any ideas on how I can fix this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the comand to fix this from a boot disk (you can create one from the WAIK or boot to the recovery environment from the install media) `bcdboot c:\windows`

BCDboot documentation is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744347(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that! Not working though :(

Comment: Did BCDboot run?

Comment: yes it did, but it would give back "no element found" ... I gave up and reinstalled Win7

Comment: OK then next step would have been to use the wrinre environment to repair the missing files

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with putting in the Windows installation CD then booting. Choose to repair installation and let it chug away. If it is missing or has corrupted boot files, the repair can do wonders. Just be careful on what you click so you don't accidentally re-write your entire drive.