# Windows 7 will not boot, but installation is found

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I get an error that says no bootable device is found. I boot into WinRE from the Win7 DVD and run bootrec /scanos : returns that there is an installation at C:\Windows
However, doing a bootrec /rebuildbcd shows me the OS, i select it, then get Element not found.

This is a customized OS I am playing with the partitions on(to fit a company-wide imaging scheme, I used GParted to move and resize the partitions) so i can't just re-image it.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/132356/79358

Comment: @Diogo when i try to do what is suggested in that thread I get an error copying boot files

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 2 options:
1. reinstall
2. do an in-place upgrade but I am not familiar with that

[Windows7 in-place upgrade](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2255099)

Comment: To do an in place upgrade, the user needs to be able to boot to normal mode on vista or 7

Answer (score 0):

Try to download Windows 8 DVD (Trial) and boot it from there, there is the options to fix the booting process (including recovery the files necessary to boot your OS), it'll be more advanced than Windows 7 boot recovery options. It's worth to try.